# Multiple identical HTTP requests in single service call

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I have WCF service hosted on IIS 7.5 communicating via HTTP protocol. It is confugured as customBinding, see below. It requires session and it has no protection level yet.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="customHttpBinding" openTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" closeTimeout="00:15:00">
      <reliableSession ordered="false" />
      <security requireSignatureConfirmation="false"  enableUnsecuredResponse="true" />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004" />
      <httpTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Client is MS Excel AddIn that on user's purpose call asynchronously 6 different operation contracts. Everything works and looking good until I open Fiddler. There I see multiple identical HTTP requests:

[image]

I browsed the content of these identical responses and it really holds identical data. In debug mode I made myself sure that the client calls every operation contract one time only and the service method runs one time only as well.

The question is how to reduce multiple requests?

In the past I have that configured as wsHttpBinding and the data was not requested multiple times but we need a little more control over configuration as it will be deployed on multiple servers.

I don't want to transfer the same data multiple times on the network, in other cases I need to transfer larger data (about hundreds of MB).

**UPDATE**

According to spodger question, here is client configuration:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="customHttpBinding" openTimeout="00:15:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:15:00" closeTimeout="00:15:00">
    <reliableSession ordered="false" acknowledgementInterval="00:00:30" inactivityTimeout="00:15:00" flowControlEnabled="true" />
      <security requireSignatureConfirmation="false"  enableUnsecuredResponse="true"   />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004"  />
      <httpTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" requestInitializationTimeout="00:10:00" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Comment: If you look at the timings you'll see that the repeated requests are being made before the response to the first request has been received so presumably there's a very short timeout for receiving a response in the client so I'd look there.

Comment: It seems to me as a good idea, I modify the config section to add acknowledgementInterval="00:00:30" inactivityTimeout="00:15:00" and requestInitializationTimeout="00:10:00" but it has no effect. Which property I should set and how?

Comment: What is the WCF client configuration in your MS Excel AddIn?